# How to get dimensions from URL string using bash

Tags: bash, macos

I am using bash on mac and have a URL string that I want to extract the width and height values from a url containing dimensions like any of below:

```
url=domain.com/project/asset_300x250_july2/
url=domain.com/project/300x250_asset_july2/
url=domain.com/project/asset_300x250/
```

I figure I need to search for occurrences of numbers before the 'x', and then numbers after 'x'. Is there an easy way to get this? Something similar to this, which only extracts all the numbers:

```
width="${url//[!0-9]/}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a regex for such a task. Assuming your dimensions follow the syntax as in the question `[0-9]x[0-9]` you can do something like below.

The regex support in `bash` allows to match and capture strings, which will be populated in the array `BASH_REMATCH`. The index of the matched elements start from 1

A proper script could be written in detail as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regex='([[:digit:]]{1,})x([[:digit:]]{1,}).*$'

if [[ $url =~ $regex ]]; then
    printf '%s x %s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

A command-line friendly version of it would be to do

```
[[ $url =~ $regex ]] && { width="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; height="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ; }
```